# Spring 20 update to Lightning Web Components - Benefits and Support community wiki

Tags: discussion

For transparency and to invite review, I just updated the community wiki answer for the question [Lightning Web Components - Benefits and Support](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/243763/498).

Main changes:

- Verified the "supported" versus "unsupported" list match current docs for Spring 20 and updated to state "as of Spring 20"
- Mentioned and linked to the beta release notes for Lightning Message Service
- Updated the "LWC is pretty limited in this release" statement, which is now a year old and based on the very first GA release to state "Since its release a year ago, lots of features have been added".
- Incorporated the statements about missing Auradocs features into the "missing features" section.
- Added additional information about the `sfdx-lwc-jest` Jest testing plugin, including link to the NPM page.

Answer (score 5):

That's exactly why I made it a wiki; I knew it would be quickly outdated and need updating. Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox!